# Open and View Document file Url

Tags: ios, iphone

How to open and view url of documents file which is got from web service using QLPreviewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The documentation can explain well about this, but, you would like try to make your own viewer. Good luck!

See:

[Oficial topic IOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW15)

You can make as the site show: "Creating and Configuring a Document Interaction Controller"

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL) fileURL
usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {

UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

return interactionController;}
```

"Once you have a document interaction controller, you can use its properties to get information about the associated file including its name, type, and URL."

Comment: Yes, but creating you own script. Without reources explicitly pf the language.

Answer (score 0):

1. Display some kind of progress spinner.
2. Download the file to your `~/documents` folder using `URLSession` and `URLSessionDownloadTask`.
3. Hide progress spinner.
4. Then you need to create an instance of a class that implements `QLPreviewControllerDataSource` and holds your document.
5. Hide progress spinner and present `QLPreviewController`

   ```
   import UIKit
   import QuickLook


   class Document: NSObject, QLPreviewItem {
       var previewItemURL: URL?
   }

   class PreviewDataSource: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {

       var document: Document?

       func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
           return document != nil ? 1 : 0
       }

       func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
           return document!
       }
   }

   class ProgressLoadingViewController: UIViewController {

       var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
       var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

       var dataSource: PreviewDataSource?

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           startDownload()
       }

       func startDownload() {
           // start progres spinner
           downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: URL(string: "http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf")!) { [weak self] (downloadLocation, response, error) in
               guard // check if download went correctly
                   error != nil,
                   let filename = response?.suggestedFilename,
                   let downloadLocation = downloadLocation
                   else {
                       print("Something went wrong: \(error!)")
                       return
               }

               // copy file
               let fileManager = FileManager.default
               let targetPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename, relativeTo: fileManager.temporaryDirectory)
               do {
                   try fileManager.copyItem(at: downloadLocation, to: targetPath)
               } catch let fileError {
                   print("Copying failed: \(fileError)")
                   return
               }

               // prepare preview
               let document = Document()
               document.previewItemURL = targetPath
               self?.dataSource? = PreviewDataSource()
               self?.dataSource?.document = document

               let qlViewController = QLPreviewController()
               qlViewController.dataSource = self?.dataSource

               // hide progress spinner
               self?.present(qlViewController, animated: true) {
                   self?.downloadTask = nil
                   qlViewController.reloadData()
               }
           }
           downloadTask?.resume()
       }
   }
   ```

Of course this long completion function should be split up into several and then moved to its own class `DocumentDownloadManager`.

Comment: can u answer me for objective C?? @orkoden