# Present Files document from URL

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument

I am trying to find a way to present a document, file, image (anything that's within the iCloud Drive folder) to a user from the file's URL.

Let's say that I present a `document picker` to the user with the regular `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and the user selects a document.

With the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate's` `didPickDocumentAt url: URL` I get the selected file/document URL and I store it somewhere.

Later I want to present the selected document based on that stored `URL`, what's the best way to do it?

I have tried `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` but I don't think I can achieve it with that (or I might have done it wrong).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If a file is an Image or a PDF I can show it within a `WKWebView` but the file could be of any type and I want to avoid the type check of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this by using `QuickLook`

I have followed the answer from this post.

[Open and View Document file Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449997/open-and-view-document-file-url)